# Display map on basis of previous activity

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

How can I show a particular city's map by clickin on a button of previous activity..for eg: In activity one I typed New York in edittext and clicked button and it opened Activity two containing map and points to New York city...I also want to show the tourist attractions in newyork by different markers.... Can someone show me a way or tut for this..thanks in advance

I have done with a map showing nearby locations although it doesn't update the location.. :(
any help wud be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to pass the city name to the Map activity.

Do the following in activity one:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapActivity.class);
i.putExtra("location","New York");
startActivity(i);
```

To retrieve the value do the following in your Map activity:

```
String location = getIntent().getExtras().getString("location");
```

Comment: I know how to pass data in intents but how will u use String location to show the map of NewYork? This is the thing i wanted to know that what happens after passing location in intents...

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot of questions you are asking here in one question.

To find a city by it's address and present it on the map you wound need to create a `Geocoder` that will give the city coordinates you can check this tutorial for that:

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-geocoding-showing-user-input-location-on-google-map-android-api-v2/

here is an AsyncTask code snippet that is presented there to access the Geocoder service:

```
// An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service
private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Clears all the existing markers on the map
        googleMap.clear();

        // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
        for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){

            Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

            // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

            String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
            address.getCountryName());

            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(addressText);

            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Locate the first location
            if(i==0)
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }
    }
}
```

now for the turist attractions you will have to query some kind of service that will provide you with such information parse it and present it on the map as well.